# How to get cell value using column name and row number using open XML Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, openxml

In my project I use selenium c# to develop scripts. I am building a data driven framework where I can read data from excel file using column name and row number to feed the data to web elements.

First tried, Linq and excel data reader to read the data but I got below error which I couldn't able to resolve.

"System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib, Version=0.85.5.452, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Then I tried Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to read the data from excel file but it was very slow. Googled to found quick and fast way to read data from excel and found Open XML would be good option to read data from excel. But I did not find any relevant post which I can refer.

I want basically a function with return type as string and two parameter to fetch the value would be row number and column name.

public static string ReadExcelVal( int rowNum, string ColName)
{
}

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try this library: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=npoi which not require Micro  Excell be installded

Comment: Hi yong, Sorry for the delayed response. No, I have not tried  archive.codeplex.com/?p=npoi. Above link did not work for me. Can you please provide more detail on it or a URL to refer.

Comment: Sorry, this library moved to github now, you can find it at here: https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi  And a new one build upon this , but use .net standard 2.0 version can be found here: https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI